# How to decide the meaning of "Apparent"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, adjectives, adverbs

I was reading the meaning of the word *apparent*. I found that the word has two completely opposite meanings,
1. Easy to recognize that something is true.
2. Something seems to be true but might not be.

Now, how do I decide which meaning fits in which sentence. E.g. consider these sentences,

> 1. The sun is apparently yellow.
> 2. It is apparent that the sun is yellow.

Does this sentence mean that *it is easy to recognize that sun is yellow*, or does it mean that *the sun seems to be yellow but it isn't yellow actually*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my understanding, *"apparent"* only means that what you are saying is about <s>*appearance*</s>, a thing seen, an aspect or a look.

It does not decree if it is **true** but that what you are talking about is only from an **outside point of view**.

It is with context that you can say if it is sarcastic/false or true.

---

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparent) :

> **apparent** (comparative *more apparent*, superlative *most apparent*)
>
> - Capable of being seen, or easily seen; open to view; visible to the eye; within sight or view.
> - Clear or manifest to the understanding; plain; evident; obvious; known; palpable; indubitable.
> - Appearing to the eye or mind (**distinguished** from, but not necessarily opposed to, true or real); seeming.

Comment: Just below that wiktionary article there are [usage notes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparent#Usage_notes), which say _apparent_ has two completely opposite meanings.

Comment: No, not two meanings.  Two uses.  We use it when appearance agrees with the truth, and we use it when it disagrees.  "The sun appears yellow" is a good statement, and it means the same thing regardless of whether the sun is yellow or white.  We can agree about the apparent color even while we argue about the true color.

Comment: In the first sentence "_It was apparent that no one knew the answer. (=No one knew the answer, and it showed.)_" they say that it was _Clearly true_ that no one knew the answer. Can it mean that actually someone knew the answer but it seemed that no one knew?

Comment: @user31782 The sentence is based on the "apparent" meaning that is near of "it is true/clear that..." but it is only BASED on something seen, not something certified true

Comment: So we use "Apparent", (1) when we are confident that something is true/false -- but not 100% sure, and (2) when we just make guess about something -- which makes the statement less decisive.

Comment: Your (1) is correct, your (2) need to refer to visual aspect which make the guess unsure and probably false.

Comment: If I get it right then, (1) _It is apparent that the sun is yellow._ **= confident statement**. (2) _The apparent color of sun is yellow._ **= less decisive statement.**. I'm not sure to which category (3) _The Sun is apparently yellow_ fall. I guess (3) is also a confident statement.

Comment: The different meanings are **not defined** by the sentence form. Only context can help. Your two sentences are under the (1)

Comment: What about _(3) The Sun is apparently yellow fall._ Does it require context?

Comment: (1) The sun looks definitely yellow to everyone, it doesn't count a lot how you are saying it. **But** if in a post about how we are perceiving colors, you say *"It is apparent that the sun is yellow."*, the meaning is clear that this yellow color is not true.

Comment: You meant to say that if the line _It is apparent that the sun is yellow_, was written with a physics context explaining Sun emits is a mixture of radiations of different wavelength then it would mean that the sun just appears to be yellow but it is isn't actually yellow. So basically the same statement can be more decisive or less desisive depending upon the context.

Comment: @user31782 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiomatic English usage of 'apparent/apparently', which is almost sarcastic:

> "Did you read the politician's explanation for accepting that bribe?
>   Apparently, he was going to donate the money to an orphanage."

Here, we understand that the given reason originated from the politician himself but our use of the word 'apparently' implies that we don't believe it. Even more confusing would be the sentence :

> "Apparently, he was going to donate the money to an orphanage, but it
>   was apparent that the money was intended for himself."